# How can I update my boost version when I am not allowed to sudo?

Tags: python, linux, boost

I am a newbie for both Python and this website and I would like to obtain your assistance for this problem

I am on a Project where I have to log-into a remote cluster for batch process.

I have been confronted by this problem for 1 week by now, have been searching for possible solutions here and AskUbuntu, but none of them worked.

---

I am trying to configure $HOME/external/LHAPDF-6.1.6

Code

```
ssh -XY trentacoollime@starbucks.com

cd external/LHAPDF-6.1.6


./configure --prefix=$HOME/external
```

Terminal

> checking for Cython >= 0.19... no
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -pedantic flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Wall flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Wno-long-long flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Qunused-arguments flag... no
>
> checking for Boost headers version >= 1.41.0... no
>
> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0

In order to solve problem

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

However, when I attempt to execute the code,

> trentacoollime is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

In order to make myself as sudoer, I almost tried all methods given in this website, but none of them worked.

**A SHORT** list of my referrals include these links

https://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179954/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported

https://askubuntu.com/questions/124166/how-do-i-add-myself-into-the-sudoers-group

https://askubuntu.com/questions/151200/my-main-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file

---

**Please note that, when I am in my own machine (outside of the cluster), it gave me the same terminal error of**

> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0

for the first attempt. However, when I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

it made me to successfully configure the LHAPDF-6.1.6

---

Thus, I believe the sudo libboost install code is the good answer, but I would like to find out how to implement in my cluster environment.

Given that my advisor told me in this cluster, it would never work anyway and I should not try to do so, I concluded finding a new method to add myself as a sudoer is **not an option**

Thus, for my neophyte idea of possible answers are

- I wonder if there is any good method with linking the boost version, that exists in my own machine from installation to the my trentacoollime remote cluster account
- I have these (and some others that also have title of libboost)
  (my home directory is /storage/5/home)

  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.5

Can I exploit any out of these library guys?

- Your any other ingenious idea!

I really appreciate your help

I would love to break this thing and hope for a simple explanation that I could learn.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Someone is administrating the cluster- youve got access. Ask an admin to of the cluster to add the needed package for you? There are reasons not everyone gets superuser rights ...

Comment: You can't replace the system-wide version, but you could install a local version along-side (given enough space/compute time). Circumventing sudo privileges is simply that: fraud/abuse (and should be impossible). Don't do it.